# Surface delimited by an elliptical cylinder and z+y = 9.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

We're covering Stokes' Theorem in class right now, and I can't understand anything. I'm struggling to solve even the most trivial examples. Here's one I can't solve: Calculate the surface integral of $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = (z,x,y)$ where the surface $S$ is the surface delimited by $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9} = 1$ and $z+y=9$. What do I do? I feel like I should solve for $x$ and $y$ and then find a parametric curve in $z$. But then what's the surface associated with it? Should I solve $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9} - 1 = z + y - 9$ instead? Would that be a surface? I have no idea what is going on. A hint towards a general approach to solve these types of problems would help also.

Comment: I recommend to read Stokes' Theorem in Wikipedia. To find surface integral you need to represent $\mathbf{F}$ as $\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$. Your problem statement is not full. Given equations define two surfaces: elliptic-cylindrical and plain. They delimit some volume. To define surface, author should change one of equations to inequality. I believe, it is something like $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}\leq 1$. Then you can make some parametrization of your surface: $x=2u \cos v$, $y=3u \sin v$, $z=9-3u \sin v$, $u\in[0;1]$, $v\in[0;2\pi]$. Using Stokes' you'll transform surface integral to linear

Comment: To add on to what Ivan is saying, it seems like you misread the question. Most likely the question is not asking for the surface integral of that vector field, but the line integral because two equations that you say denote the surface actually denote a line, because there are two equal signs (as opposed to one equal sign and an inequality). But then it could ask you to compute a surface integral instead by making your own surface integral via Stokes' theorem. The reason I suspect that is because undoing a curl is difficult, but your field has a simple curl if you take it.

Comment: @NinadMunshi It asks to solve both the line integral and the surface integral. I'm not sure, but it just says $S$ is delimited by those two. For the surface integral, I think we have to consider the plane $z = 9-y$ and then find a region to integrate such that the plane is bounded by the elliptical cylinder. Could that be it?

Comment: For Stokes' theorem, the surface is never unique, only the line is - there are an infinite number of surfaces that you could choose from so long as they all share the same boundary line (the boundary in this case being the intersection between the cylinder and the plane)

Comment: OP's interpretation (the integral of $\mathbf{F}$ over the elliptical surface) gives $0$, and requires computation of some "anti-curl" to apply Stokes' theorem. Ninad Munshi's interpretation (the integral of $\mathbf{F}$ over the elliptical line) gives $12\pi$ and has a more straightforward application of Stokes' theorem (the curl of $\mathbf{F}$ is $(1, 1, 1)$, while the "ant-curl" of $\mathbf{F}$ is not unique and can be $(-y^2/2, -z^2/2, -x^2/2)$ or $(xz, xy, yz)$, for example).

Comment: @wimi What's the equation of the elliptical line that you found? That's probably what it is.

Comment: @Cairo2003 the elliptical line is $(2\cos \theta, 3\sin \theta, 9-3\sin\theta)$, for $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to interpret the question as computing the line integral of $\mathbf{F}(x, y, z)=(z, x, y)$ over the **closed curve** given by the intersection of the elliptical cylinder $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9} = 1$ and the plane $y+z=9$. The reason I interpret it like this is twofold: the elliptical cylinder and the plane do not "delimit" any finite surface, and the alternative interpretation of computing the surface integral over some ellipse requires computation of an "anti-curl", which is less straightforward. In any case, the alternative interpretation can be solved in the same way by noting that $(xz, xy, yz)$ is an anti-curl of $\mathbf{F}$.

The intersection of the elliptical cylinder and the plane is a closed curve $C$ that can be parameterized as
$$(x, y, z)=(2\cos\theta, 3\sin\theta, 9-3\sin\theta),\qquad \theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$$

##### Calculation using Stokes' theorem

Stokes' theorem says
$$\oint_C\mathbf{F}(x, y, z)\cdot d\boldsymbol{\ell}=\iint_S \left(\nabla\times\mathbf{F}(x, y, z)\right)\cdot d\mathbf{S}$$
where $S$ is any surface whose boundary is $C$.

The curl of $\mathbf{F}$ is
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{F}(x, y, z)=(1, 1, 1)$$
We choose $S$ to be the surface in the plane $y+z=9$ that is delimited by the curve $C$. A parameterization of $S$ is
$$(x, y, 9-y),\qquad x\in[-2, 2], y\in\left[-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{36-9x^2},\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{36-9x^2}\right]$$
and the differential of surface is
$$d\mathbf{S}=(0, 1, 1)\:dy\:dx$$
Note that the norm of $d\mathbf{S}$ must be the area of the surface element, which is $\sqrt{2}$ in this case.

We compute the surface integral:
\begin{align*}
\iint_S \left(\nabla\times\mathbf{F}(x, y, z)\right)\cdot d\mathbf{S} & = \int_{x=-2}^{2} \int_{y=-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{4-x^2}} (1, 1, 1) \cdot (0, 1, 1) \:dy\: dx \\
& = \int_{x=-2}^{2} \int_{y=-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{4-x^2}} 2 \:dy\: dx \\
& = \int_{x=-2}^{2} 6\sqrt{4-x^2} \:dy\: dx \\
& = 12\pi.
\end{align*}

##### Direct computation of the line integral

The line integral can also be computed directly. The differential of length is
$$d\boldsymbol{\ell}=(-2\sin\theta, 3\cos\theta, -3\cos\theta)\:d\theta$$
so the line integral is
\begin{align*}
\oint_C\mathbf{F}(x, y, z)\cdot d\boldsymbol{\ell} & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mathbf{F}(2\cos\theta, 3\sin\theta, 9-3\sin\theta)\cdot (-2\sin\theta, 3\cos\theta, -3\cos\theta)\:d\theta \\
& = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (9-3\sin\theta, 2\cos\theta, 3\sin\theta)\cdot (-2\sin\theta, 3\cos\theta, -3\cos\theta)\:d\theta \\
& = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left[-18\sin\theta + 6\sin^2\theta + 6 \cos^2\theta - 9\sin\theta\cos\theta  \right]\:d\theta \\
& = 12\pi.
\end{align*}

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!